# How do I get some value in the IntervalIndex ?

Tags: python, pandas

The variable 'lvl' is IntervalIndex type like following this.

```
lvl = IntervalIndex([(1.418, 1.69], (1.69, 6.696], (6.696, 7.217], (7.217, 7.845], (7.845, 10.11] ... (17.648, 18.199], (18.199, 19.315], (19.315, 20.16], (20.16, 22.471], (22.471, 25.009]]
          closed='right',
          dtype='interval[float64]')
```

Now I've try to append some index value like this:

```
for each in val_list:  
    for k in range(len(lvl)):
        lower_val = float(lvl[k][1:-1].split(',')[0])
        upper_val = float(lvl[k][1:-1].split(',')[-1])
        if each >=lower_val and each <= upper_val:
            some_var_index.append(k)
```

But, error raise to me... :

```
{TypeError}'pandas._libs.interval.Interval' object is not subscriptable
```

How do I this? 
Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Object being not subscriptable means it does not behave like ordinary list, but you doing it twice here:

```
lower_val = float(lvl[k][1:-1].split(',')[0])
upper_val = float(lvl[k][1:-1].split(',')[-1])
```

with second square bracket `[1:-1]`. Instead those two lines use this one:

```
lower_val, upper_val = lvl[k].left, lvl[k].right
```

and you should be good.

Comment: Thank you soooooo much, Mkos!